# Facebook login stuck in permissions page in dispaly=touch mode- windows 8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webview, webbrowser-control, windows-8

I was trying to implement Facebook login in windows 8 application . I am using following url to request Facebook login

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&response_type=token&scope=email%2coffline_access%2cpublish_stream&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fwww.facebook.com%2fconnect%2flogin_success.html&display=touch
```

I am using webview to request this url .I am getting the login page correctly shown below.
[image]

After user enter login credential it is getting redirecting to another page and getting stuck there.I guess that page is supposed to be given permissions.I am attaching a screen shown below

[image]

Nothing will happen if i click on cancel or install ..

if i am removing `display=touch` from the request everything will works fine.But the login poge and permissions page are displayed like in web browser.That is not optimized for touch ..

I have tested the same with `webbrowser` control in wpf..But the problem is still exisiting there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows 8 You should be using [WebAuthenticationBroker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker).

Here is code example:

```
private async void Authenticate()
    {
        //Facebook Authentication Uri
        var facebookUri = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";
        //Standard redirect uri for desktop/non-web based apps
        var redirectUri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        //Place your appa client id here
        var clientId = "";
        //The type of token that can be requested
        var responseType = "token";
        //Response pattern
        var pattern = string.Format("{0}#access_token={1}&expires_in={2}", redirectUri, "(?.+)", "(?.+)");

        try
        {
            String FacebookURL = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" +
                clientId + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(redirectUri) + "&scope=read_stream&display=touch&response_type=token";

            System.Uri StartUri = new Uri(FacebookURL);
            System.Uri EndUri = new Uri(redirectUri);


            WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                                    WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                                    StartUri,
                                                    EndUri);
            if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                var response = WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString();
            }
            else if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
            {
                //Handle HTTP error
            }
            else
            {
                //Handle error
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle error
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have used it sccessfully.How Can i edit the the popup if i am using WebAuthenticationBroker

Comment: The idea of using WebAuthenticationBroker is to have a default look when authenticating to somewhere using OAuth.